# Web API call from a ASP.NET MVC5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a new web application with MVC template and core references having MVC and Web API.

I want to handle all the business logic through Web API controller. I have a login page view, where on form submit i want to make a call to the Web API method with the form data.

Login.cshtml

```
<form action="/api/Authorization/Login" method="post">
<div>
    UserName: <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    Password: <input type="password" name="UserPassword" id="UserPassword" value="" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="BtnSubmit" value="Login" />
</div>
```

I have added a Web API controller in the controller folder with the name 'Authorization' and on the above form submit, I'm not able to reach the method 'Login'.

Authorization Web API controller:

```
public class AuthorizationController : ApiController
{
    public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string UserPassword)
    {
        // method logic
    }
}
```

On form submit ending up with the following screen,
[image]

Please let me know what am i missing here so that i can reach the method defined under the api controller?

Also have not added any new route configs, the only config present in webApiConfig.cs is,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a [HttpPost] attribute above your Login() function. As it is your method will only work for GET requests.

This page will help you out: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1